# Why does this graphics loop freeze my gui?

Tags: java, loops, user-interface

So to my eyes this code looks fine but I can't really tell is it good because it freezes the whole painting loop. it worked fine before without all that offset hassling.

```
    int offsetX = 0;
    int offsetY = 0;

    for(int y = 0, canvasY = offsetY + y, x = 0, canvasX = offsetX + x; canvasY < mapHeight + offsetY && canvasX < mapWidth + offsetX; y++, x++) {
            int tileToPaint = canvasX + (canvasY * mapWidth);
            tileObject = getObject(tileToPaint);
            int locationX = tileSize * x;
            int locationY = tileSize * y;
            draw(tileObject, locationX, locationY);
    }
```

Comment: What framework?  SWT, Swing, AWT....? From the sounds of it, you have created a infinite loop.  Try using a debugger to check the states of your variables and verify the escape condition

Comment: Needs canvasY++ and canvasX++ at end of loop.  PS your for statement is doing too much.

Comment: That's _for loop_ is insane.  For loops are meant to be simple and easy to read.

Comment: Try writing code _that you can read._

Comment: @ThomasW - Seriously... That's a comment I want to make to 90% of the OPs who post questions like this.  If you actually make your code easy to read, you make your errors easy to find in the process ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that it's infinite.

Your condition:

```
canvasY < mapHeight + offsetY && canvasX < mapWidth + offsetX
```

Will always be false, since none of those values ever change.

---

What I believe you want to do is to call these after the `draw` call.

```
canvasY = offsetY + y;
canvasX = offsetX + x;
```

Comment: that solved the infinite loop but it renders weirdly ex. normally it would be: 
0-0-0-0
0-0-0-0
0-0-0-0
but now its like
0- - -
 -0- -
 - -0- sorry for poor explanation, its kind of not your business :P

Comment: @user2483938 -- write a clear loop, that you & other people can read and infer what it's _meant_ to do. This is your error & dodgy code, not anybody else's.

Comment: @user2483938 I apologize for not being able to provide a fully working answer. It was a challenge enough trying to even produce one.

Comment: @ThomasW yeah, didn't I just say it or what?